# spring-security global-method-security protect-pointcut with @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity

Tags: spring, spring-security

How does one port from

```
<sec:global-method-security secured-annotations="disabled">
    <sec:protect-pointcut expression='execution(* x.y.z.end*(..))' access='...' />
```

to spring java-config

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

?

There is a simmilar question here http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/726615-protect-pointcut-in-java-configuration

Answer (score 2):

There's a workaround for it. The security points information is kept in `MethodSecurityMetadataSource` implementations (which are then used by `MethodInterceptor`) so we have to create an additional `MethodSecurityMetadataSource`. As mentioned in the spring forum post the xml pointcut configuration is kept in `MapBasedMethodSecurityMetadataSource` and processed by `ProtectPointcutPostProcessor`. we also need an instance of `ProtectPointcutPostProcessor`. Unfortunately this class is final and package-private so there are 2 options:

1. create your own class and copy/paste the whole content of the original one (that's what I did)
2. change the class modifiers with reflection and create an instance of the original one (haven't done that so no idea if it would work fine)

then create the following beans in your context:

```
@Bean
public Map<String, List<ConfigAttribute>> protectPointcutMap() {
    Map<String, List<ConfigAttribute>> map = new HashMap<>();

    // all the necessary rules go here
    map.put("execution(* your.package.service.*Service.*(..))", SecurityConfig.createList("ROLE_A", "ROLE_B"));

    return map;
}

@Bean
public MethodSecurityMetadataSource mappedMethodSecurityMetadataSource() {

    // the key is not to provide the above map here. this class will be populated later by ProtectPointcutPostProcessor
    return new MapBasedMethodSecurityMetadataSource();
}

// it's either the original spring bean created with reflection or your own copy of it
@Bean
public ProtectPointcutPostProcessor pointcutProcessor() {
    ProtectPointcutPostProcessor pointcutProcessor = new ProtectPointcutPostProcessor((MapBasedMethodSecurityMetadataSource) mappedMethodSecurityMetadataSource());
    pointcutProcessor.setPointcutMap(protectPointcutMap());
    return pointcutProcessor;
}
```

we've created the necessary beans, now we have to tell spring to use them. I'm assuming you're extending `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration`. by default it creates `DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource` which contains a list of other `MethodSecurityMetadataSource`s. Depending on what you want to achieve you have following options:

1. if you want to keep all the other `MethodSecurityMetadataSource`s (like the ones for parsing the `@Secured` annotations) you can extend the list in the delegating metadata source by overriding the following method:

   ```
   @Override
   protected MethodSecurityMetadataSource customMethodSecurityMetadataSource() {
       return mappedMethodSecurityMetadataSource();
   }
   ```

it would inject it on first place in the list though which may cause some problems.

2. if you want to keep the other sources but want yours to be the last in the list then override the following method:

   ```
   @Override
   public MethodSecurityMetadataSource methodSecurityMetadataSource() {
       DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource metadataSource = (DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource) super.methodSecurityMetadataSource();
       metadataSource.getMethodSecurityMetadataSources().add(mappedMethodSecurityMetadataSource());
       return metadataSource;
   }
   ```
3. if you want your source to be the only one (you don't want to use `@Secured` or any other annotations) then you can override the same method, just with different content

   ```
   @Override
   public MethodSecurityMetadataSource methodSecurityMetadataSource() {
       return mappedMethodSecurityMetadataSource();
   }
   ```

that's it! I hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

I followed @marhewa comments and have been able to use the Spring version of class `ProtectPointcutPostProcessor` by defining the following bean

```
  /**
   * Needed to use reflection because I couldn't find a way to instantiate a
   * ProtectPointcutPostProcessor via a BeanFactory or ApplicationContext. This bean will process
   * the AspectJ pointcut defined in the map; check all beans created by Spring; store the matches
   * in the MapBasedMethodSecurityMetadataSource bean so Spring can use it during its checks
   * 
   * @return
   * @throws Exception
   */
  @Bean(name = "protectPointcutPostProcessor")
  Object protectPointcutPostProcessor() throws Exception {
    Class<?> clazz =
        Class.forName("org.springframework.security.config.method.ProtectPointcutPostProcessor");

    Constructor<?> declaredConstructor =
        clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(MapBasedMethodSecurityMetadataSource.class);
    declaredConstructor.setAccessible(true);
    Object instance = declaredConstructor.newInstance(pointcutMethodMetadataSource());
    Method setPointcutMap = instance.getClass().getMethod("setPointcutMap", Map.class);
    setPointcutMap.setAccessible(true);
    setPointcutMap.invoke(instance, pointcuts());

    return instance;
  }
```

This way I don't need to duplicate the code of this Spring class.

Cheers